# Lucene Memory Usage

Tags: java, lucene, jpype

I am indexing ~250.000 Documents, but hit OOME after around 200.000 (before that, it gets really slow until the GC limit is hit).

The code looks like this (I am using jpype):

```
def index_documents(self, documents):
    writer = IndexWriter(self.store, self.config)
    for document in documents:
        self.indexDocument(document,writer)

    writer.commit()
    writer.close()

def indexDocument(self, document, writer):
    doc = Document()
    doc.add(Field('text',document['text'],TextField.TYPE_STORED))
    doc.add(Field('title',document['title'],TextField.TYPE_STORED))
    doc.add(Field('url',document['url'],StringField.TYPE_STORED))
    doc.add(Field('domain',document['domain'],StringField.TYPE_STORED))
    doc.add(Field('category',document['category'],StringField.TYPE_STORED))

    writer.addDocument(doc)
```

I would expect that Documents and Fields get flushed and then garbage collected every once in a while, so it shouldn't be possible to hit OOME. Instead, there seems to be a leak somewhere. How can I find out whether this is a problem with lucene or jpype? Assuming this is a lucene problem, what possibilities do I have to reduce memory usage? Can I diagnose how often a flush occurs or something like that?

Comment: Seems like it's the `writer` that needs flushing. Since it's commited only after all the documents are processed (causing the OOME).

Comment: @Kayaman Did I understand the documentation wrong? It seemed to me the flush should be automatic after a certain memory usage / document count.

Comment: Indeed. You should run `jvisualvm` on it to see what's happening with the memory.

Comment: @Kayaman Thank you, it has been a while since I last used jvisualvm, I hadn't thought of that. I found out that it's probably one of my third-party tokenfilters that leaks memory.

Comment: There was a OOM issue in JPype that [has been fixed](https://github.com/originell/jpype/pull/124) but not yet released. Please try the current master.

Comment: @bastian Thanks, I think that is in addition to the memory leak I found. Sometimes things are more hard than they should be ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating JPype, as bastian commented, solved the issue. The fix is actually released now in version 0.6.0.

Additionally, I had a memory leak in a third-party component that I probably wouldn't have found without the Jpype bug ;-)